# Click on Label and show Div (Label name change dynamically)

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a label, give it the name Advanced Search.

When user clicked on it, a  div will be shown at the page and at the same time the label name will be changed to Basic Search.

And when user click on the Basic Search it will hide the div and change the name to Advanced Search. How to do that?

I know I need to use jquery and give an id to the div or something. But I just can't get it right for the moment. Please help!

Comment: You said you've not managed to get it right yet. Can you post the code that you've got so far, to give others something to work from?

Comment: Can you provide some your code for us to check what you are doing wrong?

Comment: You want the label name to change to 'Basic Search' or the text in the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

*HTML*

```
<label id="search">Advanced Search</label>
<div id="searchContent" style="display:none;">Something</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text === "Advanced Search") {
            $(this).text("Basic Search");
            $("#searchContent").show();
        } else {
            $(this).text("Advanced Search");
            $("#searchContent").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AM6Wz/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a minor problem here that I think it has to do with css. When user clicked the Advanced Search I want to hide the textbox next to it. And replace the Advanced Search with the Basic Search word. However, my Basic Search alignment is not accurate because the text box is hidden. What should I do?